# how to hide a panel in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

What is the best approach to show and hide an asp panel which is containing other controls like textbox and label controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try

```
document.getElementById( 'Panel1ClientId' ).style.display = 'none'; // to hide
```

and

```
document.getElementById( 'Panel1ClientId' ).style.display = 'block'; // to show
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery, you can just switch visibilty:

```
$('#<%= YourPanel.ClientID %>').hide();
$('#<%= YourPanel.ClientID %>').show();
```

Edit: jQuery is probably overkill just to hide/show, but if you plan to add more functionality client side, you should consider using it ;)

Comment: I would even recommend setting the panel's ClientIDMode to static.

Comment: Good idea to get rid of the asp.net tag soup (if he use .NET 4.0)